# Cannot Access tomcat home page but tomcat is running

Tags: linux, windows, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have installed tomcat on aws ec2 instance which has a linux os vm. I am unable to access the home page of tomcat when I put the host name in my windows system's browser.I have tried these commands to check if tomcat is working.

```
ps x | grep /opt/tomcat | grep -v grep | cut -d ' ' -f 1

ps -ef | grep tomcat | grep -v "grep tomcat" | wc -l

ps -x |grep tomcat

ps -ef|grep java.
netstat -tulpn
lsof -i
```

and 8080 port is listening and tomcat is running.
but I am unable to access tomcat home page by putting `hostname:8080` when I put this in my windows browser. What could be the problem?

Comment: what is the error you are getting? is it a forbidden error or page not found?

Comment: Do you have port 8080 open in your security rules for EC2?

Comment: I am getting this error This site can’t be reached.this hsostname took too long to respond.

Comment: Yes they are open in  security rules of EC2.